# Rails - All tests fail - ' ... ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: admins.email ... '

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run this: `rails test`, then all my (10) tests fail, with the same error (Unique constraint failed). Here's the error-message:

```
E

Error:
WelcomeControllerTest#test_the_truth:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE 
constraint failed: admins.email: INSERT INTO "admins" ("created_at", 
"updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-02-20 16:22:33.516784', '2017-02-20  
16:22:33.516784', 298486374)

bin/rails test test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb:4
```

One of the tests are this one:

```
test "the truth" do
  assert true
end
```

By browsing around, I saw that it probably was something about the fixtures. In /test/fixtures/admin.yml then this was there:

```
# This model initially had no columns defined. If you 
# add columns to the model remove the '{}' from the fixture 
# names and add the columns immediately below each fixture, 
# per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

If I then comment out `one: {}` and `two: {}`, then it works. I have no idea why this is? Can anyone explain it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't like you using two emails that are nil, it is expecting unique email addresses for each model. Change it to this:

```
# This model initially had no columns defined. If you 
# add columns to the model remove the '{}' from the fixture 
# names and add the columns immediately below each fixture, 
# per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: 
  email: 'one@one.com'

two:
  email: 'two@two.com'
```

Comment: Why isn't there any brackets in the answer, though? I tried what you wrote and it works. But why is it not `one: { ... }`, but just `one: ... ` ? It doesn't work, if I put the brackets. :-/

Comment: The comment at the top says "If you add columns to the model remove the '{}' from the fixture", so {} is only for when you want no values at all. I believe it is because YAML keys need a value or subkey, you can't have a key without a value so they use {} to signify no values are being added.